# Running on Nodejs, how to send data from JS file to HTML -- need advice on all the diff modules

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sqlite, express

What is the best way to send data from a JS (that was pulled from an sqlite db) file to an HTML file to display in a searchable table.  I am using NodeJS.  I am fairly new so if there are to do this that take more time and code I am ok with that if it helps my learning (compared to some awesome middle wear that saves a bunch of time).

I have successfully pulled the data and displayed it to the console.  I am using express as well.

Because I am new I don't want to keep using new modules the whole way through without gaining a better understanding of them. Lots of the posts I've read suggest things like ejs, ajax, jQuery and more. It would take a lot of time to start comparing them all to figure out which to use.

Any guidance on which way to go and why would be greatly appreciated.

If my question is not clear or lacking info please let me know and I'll adjust.

Comment: Is there a template library that you are using to display the HTML inside Node JS?

Comment: I would recommend jQuery. So in the JS file, you can access the HTML elements and show data. For example, you read some data as JSON from the server using a function in the JS file, when the result come back, you can show it in an HTML element such as <p> or <table> or ...

Comment: @Maramal -- I think so.  I am using express.  If I understand it correctly it is setting up the routes to the html page/s.  Is express considered a template library?

Comment: @J.K -- Thanks for the suggestion.  Currently when I pull data from the db file and console.log it, it comes out as an array.  When you say "read as JSON from the server"  does the data have to be in JSON format to use jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your node and express all setup, it's indeed easiest to use a template engine. It's basically a way to write HTML files, but it's easy to send data from Node.js directly to the HTML file. Since you're new to this concept, I recommend using `ejs`, because it looks pretty much like a regular HTML file, but with a few extra features. `pug` is also a well-known template engine, but this requires you to learn a new syntax.

1. To start using `ejs`, first run `npm install ejs` (or `npm i ejs`).
2. inside your `app.js` or `index.js`, where you setup your node and express, put 
   `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');` above all your routes and middleware.
3. Inside your root folder create a folder called `views`. It has to be called this way.
4. Now inside this folder create an ejs file e.g. `index.ejs`.

You can read more about `ejs` at [their website,](https://ejs.co) but as I said it's just the same as HTML, the only difference being the extra values your could provide from Express.

If you want to render the index.ejs

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {
    data: yourdata
  }
});
```

Here you can send the data retrieved from your database to the file. In the ejs file you can now access this data using `<%= data %>`. An example using a div:

```
<div><%= data %></div>
```

If your data is an array you can also iterate through using a for loop:

```
<% for (var item of data) { %>
  <div><%= item %></div>   
<% } %>
```

**So an easy example would be**

index.js or app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var testData = {
  test: 'test'
};

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {
    data: testData
  })
});

app.listen(PORT);
```

views/index.ejs

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <%= data.test %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And now this displays 'test' on a blank page.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this.  I'm going to give it a go.  Your breakdown gives some direction and explains why I should go that way.  Much appreciated.